# Could you give me an example of how to attach an object in Deleted state – I keep getting an exception

Tags: entity-framework

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896408%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) :

> An object in the Deleted state can only be attached when the
>   ObjectStateManager is already tracking the relationship instance.

Could you give me an example of how to attach an object in the *Deleted* state. I tried the following and got "*System.InvalidOperationException: The object being attached is in an added or deleted state. Relationships cannot be created for objects in this state*".

```
        var contact = context.Contacts.First();
        Console.WriteLine(contact.Addresses.Count()); // 2

        var address = contact.Addresses.First();

        context.Addresses.DeleteObject(address);
        contact.Addresses.Attach(address); // InvalidOperationException
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs because the object is already attached once you call DeleteObject. If you want to commit the delete, you should then call

```
context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: We can't call DeleteObject on an entity in Detached state, so entity must be attached prior to calling DeleteObject on it. As such, I'm not sure how your answer is related to my question?! I'm just trying to figure out in what situation ( since in most situations we can't ) we're able to call EntityCollection<>.Attach on an object in Deleted state

Comment: Ah it would seem you are correct. You have your calls reversed. You have to attach then delete.

Comment: "You have to attach then delete." I realize that. Code I've given was just an example of how in most situations trying to call Attach on object in Deleted state gives us exception. But the main point of a question is  related to the quote I posted, which claims that in certain situations we can also call Attach on entity in Deleted state. And that certain situation is what I want you to show me --> a situation ( ie code example ) where it's ok to call Attach on an entity in Deleted state

Comment: Oh it looks like a typo. There shouldn't be a reason to reattach a deleted object. If you want to undo the deletion, you can change the objectstate through the objectcontext.

Comment: So the quote is wrong and thus there isn't any situation where we're allowed to call Attach on an entity in Deleted state?

Comment: Not to my knowledge because in order to delete, you have to be attached, and you can only attach once. You can attach an object that references a deleted object though (I think but have been wrong before and don't have a compiler in front of me).